# How to extract code form .exe file having signature Borland Delphi 6.0 - 7.0 [Overlay]

Tags: debugging, delphi, exe

[image]when i input .exe file to PEiD v0.95 it gives output like
***"Borland Delphi 6.0 - 7.0 [Overlay]"***

Now i want to retrieve code from .exe file. So how to do that . Can any one give me right path for that.

Comment: If you never reversed a Delphi binary I would suggest you to go through these two tutorials. They should get you started on the right path:
http://octopuslabs.io/legend/blog/archives/1947/1947.htm
http://octopuslabs.io/legend/blog/archives/2044/2044.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question.. Unfortunatly thre is no tool that can provides you the original source code. But the perfect solution that I found is to use OllyDbg or IdaPro. In this way you can navigate inside the code reading ASM lenguage.

If ASM is a problem for you.. IdaPro can probably help showing a sort of pseudocode, that is not exactly like the original source code, but it can give you an idea about the CodeFlow

Comment: i have already tried IdaPro but i am not understanding anything. Can u tel me something more on it.

Comment: first of all if you want to decompile something coded with native code(C/C++/Delphi)  you need to learn at least the basics of ASM. There is no solution  about this.. Because every decompiler will retrieve the code in Assembly.. If this solved your problme please check it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, you cannot retrieve the high level code from an executable.Fire up your debugger and analyze it.